# How to access _factories property from ComponentFactoryResolver in Angular9 which was available in Angular7?

Tags: angular9, angular7-router, dynamic-routing

I used **ComponentFactoryResolver** to access all the entry component factories and then add routes of those components dynamically in Angular 7.

```
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
}

var factories = this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories']

let route: Route = {
                path: MyPath,
                component: factories[0].factory[1].componentType
            };

this.router.resetConfig(config);
```

I updated my project to Angular 9 and now **_factories** are not available in ComponentFactoryResolver.

> var factories = this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories']

It returns undefined in Angular 9. It will be great help if someone can suggest some way to access all the entry component list on the go. The problem is that I have don't any information available about the entry components from which I may recompile the components through Compiler and add their routes.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler approach might be to import the component and use it directly in place of `factories[0].factory[1].componentType`. Example:

```js
import { MyComponent } from '@app/my.component';

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
}

let route: Route = {
                path: MyPath,
                component: MyComponent
            };

this.router.resetConfig(config);
```

Comment: I want keep this routing dynamic. Let's say I don't have components directly imported to my service. That is why I was accessing it from entry component factories on the fly. But in Angular 9+, these factories aren't available.